# Is it possible in Haskell to create function that at first gets n (any natural number) element of type a and than gets n element of type b?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible in Haskell to create a function that at first gets n (any natural number) of arguments of type a and than gets n arguments of type b? If it is possible, give me an example please.

Actual use case is much more complex than described before. I am writing an application that has to deal with many command line arguments. So I googled a library for this. I really like library argParser, but it assumes that constructors with a certain argument order are passed to its combinators. Example:

```
data MyTest = MyTest Int Int

myTestParser :: ParserSpec MyTest
myTestParser = MyTest `parsedBy` reqPos "pos1" `andBy` optPos 0 "pos2"
```

Unfortunately, when a contructor has many arguments it becomes very difficult to reorder them. If the requested function exists I will try to write several combinators to deal with that problem (specifically, the function will accept n lenses and then n parameters for lenses).

Comment: "Gets" elements in what way?  As arguments?  As return values?  As values generated by some computation?

Comment: Elements as arguments

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector to take two vectors where the size of both are statically known to be the same.